# Where does the Android build process store the final image file (that gets flashed into a phone device)?

Tags: android, build-process, nexus-s

After going through the build process (found at:  http://source.android.com/source/building.html) for the master branch (or the whole Android tree, not just for a specific phone such as for NexusS), where would I be able to find the final platform image in the Android file hierarchy?  The specific image that gets flashed onto the actual phone at the very end of the process.

Reason behind this query:  I cannot do the "flashing to device" steps (such as running "$ adb reboot bootloader") as found in the link I've provided b/c the Android development environment I've set up is inside a virtual machine (Ubuntu 10.04 via VirtualBox) that exists on a server (of which I am unable to access its USB ports to directly plug in my phone).  I am currently connecting to that VM through Windows RDP (of which I am unsure if it has VRDP capability?).

Since it does not seem that I can find a solution that allows for my RDP connection to the VM to use local USB (of my physical computer, a Windows 7), I need to find the final file or files the Android build process creates (after running the "$make adb bootloader" command) so I can directly load them onto the phone (a Nexus S) on my physical computer.  Does anyone know where these image files are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `out/target/product/XXXXX` from your build directory  where `XXXXX` if your build target, `maguro` for the Galaxy Nexus for instance or `generic` for the emulator.